# Splitting vectors up and adding together using for and which loop

Tags: r

So I was given this question, Write an R function that, given a vector x and a value a, finds the smallest value of n such that the sum of the first n elements of x is bigger than a, or NA if no such n exists, once using a which loop and also with a for loop.

```
nloop=function(x,a){
sum=0
  for (i in 1:length(x))
    sum = sum + x[i]
    if (sum>a)
      end=x[i]
 end

}
```

but this always gives me the last value in the vector?
And I can't think of how I would do the which loop without using a for loop. I would change the if loop to a which loop but I don't think thats whats required?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `cumsum` to determine the cumulative sum of the vector and `which` to grab the indices of the cumulative sum that exceed `a`:

```
nloop <- function(x, a) {
  w <- which(cumsum(x) > a)
  if (length(w) >= 1) w[1]
  else NA
}
nloop(1:3, 1.5)
# [1] 2
nloop(1:3, 10)
# [1] NA
```

As a quick note, your posted code doesn't work because it doesn't return even once it finds the index of interest. It would work if you replaced `end=x[i]` with `return(i)` and `end` with `return(NA)`.

Comment: Great edit.  My own preference is to use an `ifelse` statement.  As in: `nloop <- function(x,a)  ifelse(length(w<-which(cumsum(x) > a)),w,NA)`

Comment: `nloop <- function(x,a)  which(cumsum(x) > a)[1]` works too

Comment: Hi I've tried to run the code using the changing suggested but I still keep getting the same outputs? Is it because i'm not returning the sum? Or is there something else going on?

Comment: @Sharw could you provide the code you're running that isn't giving the expected behavior?

Comment: @josilber    nloop=function(x,a){
      sum=0
      for (i in 1:length(x))
        sum = sum + x[i]
        if (sum>a)
          return(i)
      return(NA)
  
    } *(sorry can't seem to get this to post as code**